# Where did the mod button on the menu go?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

The mod option has disappeared from the main menu screen in my son's Minecraft game. How do I access mods without the option on the main screen or is there a way to make it reappear?

Comment: @Sarah Is your son using Forge for mods? If so, you must make sure that he selected the profile Forge has put in his profile dropdown.

Comment: You can say if there are mods installed by looking at the game version in main menu - left bottom corner. If there are mods, it will say how many and the version of Forge.

Answer (score 7):

If there is no mods button, that means Minecraft Forge is not installed or loaded. Forge is a tool that facilitates the use of mods in Minecraft, and is a requirement for many mods.

First, make sure you are launching the game from a profile with forge selected as the version. In the launcher, check if there is a profile with "forge" in the name in the dropdown at the bottom left corner.

If not, you'll have to install Minecraft Forge. Go to [files.minecraftforge.net](http://files.minecraftforge.net/maven/net/minecraftforge/forge/index_1.7.10.html) and download the installer for the recommended version. Run it, and it will automatically create a new profile in the launcher.

Comment: This is an old answer, so it isn't always the case anymore. For example on 1.18.2 modpacks like stoneblock 3 (forge) you will not have a mod button on the main menu, even though forge is in use.  Many things changed in the new versions, we have lost a lot of code because everyone had to rewrite pretty much everything code related. The only stuff that was portable were stuff like assets, enums, structures, but most logic had to be rewritten due to things changing so much. It was for the better but still sad we lost so many good mods.